# Date appears as number while exporting data to excel in C#

Tags: c#

```
 string fileName = "test" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
 using (package = new ExcelPackage(newFile, "file"))
 {
     generateReport();//this function generates a worksheet 
     package.Workbook.Properties.Title = @"Title of project";
     package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Sri";
     package.Workbook.Properties.Subject = @"Report";
     byte[] rawData = package.GetAsByteArray();
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");
     Response.BinaryWrite(rawData);
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
```

Hi,when i try to export datatable to excel ,columns which has date appears as numbers in the excel file.When i further check these numbers are DATEVALUE(date)(this function is used in excel) results of excel.

Comment: I'd start by taking ASP.NET out of the equation. I suspect you could reproduce the problem in a small console application which set just a few hard-coded pieces of data then saved the spreadsheet locally. That would make it much easier to help you, as we could easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: excel stores dates as numbers in terms of days since 1970 or something.

Comment: Make sure that the column type is set to "Date" in excel. It is probably set to "Number" right now. (Right click on column header -> format cells)

Comment: Thank you for your comments...let me try out this suggestions